# Weird RNG behavior

Tags: java, random, black-box-testing

I'm trying to make a black box method to test if my project is working correctly, but I'm running into some problems with the random number generation.

I have got the method laid out like this:

```
public static MathObject generateBlackBoxObject() { 
        double functionChance = 0.5;
        double maxValue = 10;
        double minValue = -10;

        if (rng.nextDouble() < functionChance)
        {
            double random = rng.nextDouble();

            if (random < 1/3)
            {
                return Add.apply(Utility.generateBlackBoxObject(), Utility.generateBlackBoxObject());
            }
            else if (random < 2/3)
            {
                return Multiply.apply(Utility.generateBlackBoxObject(), Utility.generateBlackBoxObject());
            }
            else
            {
                return Exponentiate.apply(Utility.generateBlackBoxObject(), Utility.generateBlackBoxObject());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            double random = rng.nextDouble();

            if (random < 1/2)
            {
                return Constant.create(rng.nextDouble() * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue);
            }
            else
            {
                return Variable.create(rng.nextDouble() * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

It makes use of a single `java.util.Random`, but the problem I'm having is that it is most likely to select the `Variable.create ...` path, and then the `Exponentiation.apply ...` path. It is kind of unlikely to go for `Multiply` and never (!) calls `Add.apply` or `Constant.create`

It kind of seems like the rng likes to pick the higher values more often than lower or somehow the previous random double influences the next to be higher.

Can anyone tell from this what is happening and (most likely) what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Hint: what do you think the value of the expression `1/3` is? What about `2/3` and `1/2`? What sort of division do you think that's performing?

Comment: Please don't tell me it's doing integer division

Comment: That solved it, thank you. Also that explains why I've never seen anyone use 1/3 in rng like that before.

Comment: You could use `1.0 / 3` instead, which would force a double result.

Comment: Yeah I also realized that a maximum depth would be kind of useful.